# ng-class within custom directive not observing updates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a directive that's used like this:

```
<amount value="myValue" neg-class="negative" />
```

`myValue` is a scope value (should be a number)
`negative` is simply the name of a css class.

The idea behind the directive is that I wan't to show currency to the user and when the amount that's bound is negative, negClass get's applied to the rendered element.

The problem I'm having is that when negClass is changed, the update doesn't take effect. I do see the changes in the DOM, though.

Here's my directive definition:

```
myModule.directive('amount', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<span ng-class="{ {{negClass}}: value < 0 }">{{value | currency}}</span>',
        scope: {
            value: "=",
            negClass: "@",
        }

    };
});
```

Here's a test harness that demonstrates the problem: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1563210/amtdirtest.html

Comment: seems to work fine here  http://plnkr.co/edit/4NI5AxMhXgTQxNC3waFj?p=preview   Are you using events outside of angular to do updates?

Comment: That plnkr link doesn't behave any differently than my example. "The problem I'm having is that when negClass is changed, the update doesn't take effect. I do see the changes in the DOM, though."

Comment: please update plunker demo with needed css , code etc. Is very difficult to troubleshoot without being able to update/test code. I believe problem is `negclass` is a primitive and therefore since you have isolated scope in directive does not get inherited

Comment: There's nothing to update. Go to your plunker and type 'x' into the negative class name box. Do the negative values turn green? If not, then it's not working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most of the angular directives tend to work in this way. Unless the docs specifically mention supporting interpolation (`{{...}}`) for inputs then it's safer to not rely on it, especially where the input is an **=** rather than an **@** binding.

In the case of [`ngClass`](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.4/docs/api/ng.directive%3angClass), the attribute works like a **=** binding, and there is no mention of interpolation.

What actually happens in the directive is that the attribute is [only observed in the linking phase](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.4/src/ng/directive/ngClass.js#L11) and the the actual text in the attribute is never looked at again. So while the attribute continues to change, the changes are never seen.

By the time the attribute is seen by `ngClass`, it looks something like

```
{ n: value < 0 }
```

which is still evaluated based on whatever the current `value` is in scope, but the expression itself never gets changed again.

The safe way to do what you are trying would be to create an object without using interpolation, or to just have a function that returns which class is active...Something like the following should work:

```
myModule.directive('amount', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<span ng-class="getActiveClass()">{{value | currency}}</span>',
        scope: {
            value: "=",
            negClass: "@",
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.getActiveClass = function() {
                if(scope.value < 0)
                    return scope.negClass;
            }
        }

    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Originally hadn't noticed that css was in the scope already.

Here's an approach that compiles the element dynamically using `$compile` and `$watch` to listen for changes in `negClass`

```
.directive('amount', function($compile) {
    var template='<span ng-class="{ {{negClass}}: value < 0 }">{{value | currency}}</span>'
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        value: "=",
        negClass: "@",
      },
      link:function(scope,elem,attrs){
        scope.$watch('negClass',function(){
          elem.html('').append($compile(template)(scope) )
        })

      }

    };
  });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/4NI5AxMhXgTQxNC3waFj?p=preview)**</kbd>