# How use controller variable inside a AngularJs directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

How use controller variable inside a directive . I used **popoverHtml** inside scope in directive but when i add type like this type not work :

like this : scope: { popoverHtml:'@', type: @ },

my html is :

```
 good <input type='radio' name='type' value='good' data-ng-model='type' 
data-ng-change='change(type)' />
    bad <input type='radio' name='type' value='bad' data-ng-model='type'
 data-ng-change='change(type)' />
        <next-level id='pop' popover-html='{{typeMessage}}'></next-level>
```

my controller is :

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.typeMessage = 'PopOverTest';
  $scope.type = false;
  $scope.change = function(type){
    if(type == 'good'){
      $scope.typeMessage = 'very good';
    }else if(type == 'bad'){
      $scope.typeMessage = 'very bad';
    }
  };
});
```

my directive :

```
    app.directive('nextLevel', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'EA',
                scope:{ popoverHtml:'@'},
           template: '<a ui-sref="register" tabindex="0" linkdisabled="{{type}}" 
 class="btn btn-block btn-success ng-class: {disabled: !(type)}" role="button" >next</a>',
                link: function (scope, el, attrs){
                  $(el[0]).popover({
                        trigger: 'click',
                        html: true,
                        toggle:'popover',   
                        title: 'notice !!',
                        content: scope.popoverHtml,  // Access the popoverHtml html
                        placement: 'bottom'
                    });

                  attrs.$observe('popoverHtml', function(val){
                    $(el[0]).popover('hide');
                    var popover = $(el[0]).data('bs.popover');
                     popover.options.content = val;
                    console.log(popover); 
                  })


                } 
            };   
        });
```

**demo** : https://plnkr.co/edit/wfC4DrTIp8fRIs6hEEDa?p=preview

Comment: why don't use `ui-bootstrap` popover?

Comment: strongly suggest you get rid of bootstrap.js and use angular-ui-bootstrap. Don't try to re-invent the wheel

Comment: It's working for me. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send `type` as `@` binding to the directive, if you want to use it inside `ng-class`. If you do changes to `type` in main controller, they will not be reflected in `ng-class` inside the directive. Take look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456057/ng-class-within-custom-directive-not-observing-updates).

In order to reflect changes in `ng-class` you have to pass it as an `=` binding.

Plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/z5yXiAVaMEyHBsJsXFLu?p=preview)

Comment: Can you try changing name when you pass it to directive. I have named it as button. Do something similar

Comment: I dont think its is a problem with AngularJS

Comment: Can you show your current html, directive, controller code?

Comment: In the plunker you have provided you have `<next-level id='pop' popover-html='{{typeMessage}}' button='button'></next-level>` . Is this exact line of code you have in your actual code? I see you are trying to pass `button` object to directive, but I don't see any `$scope.button` object in mainCtrl. I only see `$scope.buy`..

Comment: How does your `<next-level id='pop'` HTML look right now? Can you show it? Are you able to see button right now in your UI. Plunker you have provided does not show button..

Comment: Where are you passing `buy` object to the directive?

Comment: You have to pass `buy` object to the directive if you want `button` inside the `directive` to know about the changes you made in the `mainCtrl`

Comment: Then you have to pass `buy` to `directive`. If you dont pass `directive` will not know about it.

Comment: That's because you are not passing `buy` to directive. If you pass it you can access it by `scope.buy`

Comment: You are passing buy correctly.. There is some mistake in you `ng-class` syntax.. replace directive template with this `template: '<a ui-sref="register" tabindex="0" linkdisabled="{{buy.disable}}" class="btn btn-block btn-success" ng-class:"{ \'disabled\': !buy.disable }" role="button" >next</a>',`

Comment: console.log(scope.buy.disable)

Comment: In html do you have `buy='buy' popover-html='{{typeMessage}}'`

Comment: no i have not buy='buy' . i add it to html and it's work fine . thanks @Ravi Teja

Comment: Thats it.. you have to pass the data from the html file.. before u can access it inside directive..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39817316/how-to-dynamically-update-popover-content-angularjs-bootstrap If your question are answered feel free to accept it as answer..

Comment: How can i prevent show popover when button.disable equal to false ? because i want to run function when click button when button active but popover showing again and i don't want it